# How could a make Fluidbox.js work with tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, lightbox

I try to use the [Fluidbox](http://terrymun.github.io/Fluidbox/) script with the bootstrap tab plugin. When I click on a tab, new images appear. They are in a container and the opacity goes from 0 to 1.
By default the first container opacity is set to 1.
Fluidbox works well with that container but not with the other. I suspect that it has a link with opacity change. Any ideas?

Page with the problem: http://urlgone.com/2d0035/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems Fluidbox does not work on any images that are set to display none. And in your case inside of a parent element that is set to display none.

The way you get around this is to get fluidbox to fire before the image or element is hidden. I was using easytabs, so I placed it's call inside of a window load function which gave fluidbox enough time to fire before easytabs hid the photos.

```
$(window).load(function() {
  $("#tab-full-container").easytabs();
});
```

Comment: As you say, I finally managed to fire fluidbox each time a tab is clicked. Thank you!

Comment: That is correct — simply because JS will not be able to access the calculated width and height of hidden images, causing Fluidbox to go bonkers with the calculation.